# installing spark 1.4 on google cloud cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-compute-engine

I set up a  google compute cluster with Click to Deploy
I want to use spark 1.4  but I get spark 1.1.0 
Anyone know if it is possible to set up a cluster with spark 1.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had issues with this.  These are the steps I took:

1. Download a copy of GCE's bdutil from github  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil
2. Download the spark version you want, in this case spark-1.4.1 from the spark website and store it into a google compute bucket that you control.  Make sure it's a spark that supports the hadoop you'll also be deploying with bdutil
3. Edit the spark env file   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil/blob/master/extensions/spark/spark_env.sh
4. Change SPARK_HADOOP2_TARBALL_URI='gs://spark-dist/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz'  to SPARK_HADOOP2_TARBALL_URI='gs://[YOUR SPARK PATH]'  I'm assuming you want hadoop 2, if you want hadoop 1 make sure you change the right variable.
5. Once that's all done, from the modified bdutil, build your hadoop+spark cluster, you should have a modern version of spark after this
6. You'll have to make sure you execute the spark_env.sh with the -e command when executing bdutil, you'll need to also add the hadoop_2 env if you're installing hadoop2 which I was as well.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to try http://spark-packages.org/package/sigmoidanalytics/spark_gce , this deploys Spark 1.2.0 but you could edit the file to deploy 1.4.0.

Comment: thanks for the answer, after some research I found it easier to do using bdutil